# Why can't I compare these 2 strings?

Tags: java, android

For some reason, no matter what I type into my two textboxes, I get the matches response.
At first I was using `==` and that didn't work, so I tried switching to `if( a.equals( b ))`

I'm still stuck.

Please help!

```
package net.2TextboxesStringCompare;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.EditText;

/*
 * 2TextboxesStringCompare
 */


public class Code8 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button accept;
    EditText numberStudents, numberStudents2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        numberStudents = new EditText(this);
        numberStudents2 = new EditText(this);

        // find our button in the UI by its ID
        accept = (Button)findViewById(R.id.accept);

        // set listeners for the button. Since our current class
        // implements the OnClickListener interface
        // we can simply pass the current object ("this") into
        // the listener. The appropriate method will therefore
        // be called when the event fires.
        accept.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    /* implement an event handler that responds to click events */
    public void onClick(View v){
        String a = numberStudents.getText().toString();
        String b = numberStudents2.getText().toString();
        if( a.equals( b ) )
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Matches", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), numberStudents.getText()+" !=      
            "+numberStudents2.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you see in your toast?

Comment: you better debug the application , i m guessing you are setting their values just before comparing , may be print both values before comparison and check

Comment: It says Matches no matter what

Comment: use this : a.trim().equals(b)

Comment: where are you creating the edittext ? i can see that they are not visible to anyone then how would you compare them with each other ? 
create you edittext in the layout file and refer to them like you are referring to the button. R.id.xx . and then u can compare !

Comment: this needs downvoting.Please refer to android tutorials before asking questions.. you need xml files for layouts.

Comment: @ColinGillespie: Removed my answer. There is only one statement in if and else branch. So this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: As a side note, if you don't already, you really must understand why `==` should not normally be used to test `String`s for equality.

Comment: My understand is that == is the pointer to that location in memory for the same reason that you can't compare strings in c with = right?

Comment: Anyways I got it working now thanks for the help fellas. Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: @DanPezzin : If my code was useful for you please upvote and accept it as best answer, this will help to other beginners who will face same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Your edittext were not appearing.

Use this code:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linLayout);
```

`linLayout` is the id of your `LinearLayout` in `main.xml`, replace it whatever you have.

```
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

 numberStudents = new EditText(this);
 numberStudents2 = new EditText(this);

ll.addView(numberStudents);
ll.addView(numberStudents2);
```

*or* if you create edittext in XML layout then use:

```
numberStudents = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
numberStudents2  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
```

Comparison part:

```
if(a.trim().equals(b))
{
     // show toast
}
```

Comment: You havn't declared which editText to use,basicaly you are comparing two String objects with same data but different names thats why its always showing matches.To correct this

Comment: @Abhilash : I'm assuming that Dan doesn't create edittext in xml in question code and have a look on OR part in my answer code please.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this code. this is the way you have to check the strings which you will get from edit text  at the time of submitting or button click

```
package com.example.testr;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button1;
    EditText editText1, editText2;
    Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context=this;
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);



        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                if ((editText1.getText().toString().trim()).equals(editText2.getText().toString().trim())) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, "both are equal", 1000).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "both are not  equal", 1000).show();
                }
            }
        });




    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You havn't declared which editText to use,basicaly you are comparing two String objects with same data but different names thats why its always showing matches.To correct this

1.Go to main.xml

2.create to editText ,say editText1 and editText2

3.Now use them in ur code as follows

```
numberStudents = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTex1);
numberStudents2  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTex2);
```

now it should be fine..